# Предложение сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное?

Tags: синтаксис

```
"Она вышла замуж и изменила фамилию, поэтому мы не могли ее найти".
```

> ***Какое это предложение: сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное и почему?***
> Есть две трактовки: одна версия Грамматики -80, другая - иных грамматик. 
>  А у вас какие-нибудь версии есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Николенкова Наталья Владимировна** (кандидат филологических наук, старший преподаватель филологического факультета МГУ им. М. В. Ломоносова)

Наконец, следует сказать о зоне, в отношении которой школьные учебники, академическая грамматика и современные словари обнаруживают серьезное расхождение. Это вопрос о статусе слов ***поэтому, потому.*** Проблема определения морфологической характеристики этих единиц тесно связана с определением их функции в тексте, а значит, и с определением типа сложного предложения с использованием данных слов.

Школьные учебники считают данные слова указательными местоименными наречиями. Обобщающие учебные пособия разного рода, предназначенные для школы, в данном определении единодушны. Функцию союзных слов слова *поэтому* и *потому* не выполняют, так как не входят в группу относительно-вопросительных.

Иной точки зрения придерживается АГ-80. *Слова* потому, поэтому *и еще значительный ряд слов и сочетаний слов выполняют роль конкретизатора значения при сочинительном союзе (*и поэтому, а потому, *то же* а все-таки, и наоборот*) и часто сами выступают в роли аналогов союзов. Такого понятия, как союзный аналог, в школьной программе нет. АГ-80, введя это понятие, далее, при обсуждении синтаксического устройства русского языка, не разделяет собственно союзы и «аналоги союзов». Мы уверены, что говорить о необходимости отказаться от отраженной в школьных учебниках традиционной точки зрения не стоит. Тем более что выделенная в качестве «аналога союзов» группа слов весьма обширна, в неё входят такие слова, как (§ 1673), рассматривать которые как союзы с точки зрения традиционных понятий морфологии, вероятно, не вполне корректно.

Позиция АГ-80 основана во многом на взглядах академика В.В.Виноградова, который говорил о наметившемся в русском языке переходе наречий в служебные слова, в том числе в союзы. Гибридные слова, по его определению (которое он вводит вслед за А.М.Пешковским), приобрели союзный оттенок сравнительно недавно, поэтому совмещают «союзные функции.) с грамматическими значениями наречий».

Главной проблемой при введении понятия «союзного аналога» для слов *потому, поэтому* будет характеристика предложений с использованием этих слов: *Он пришел поздно, поэтому меня не застал.* Исходя из традиционного понимания морфологического статуса «поэтому» данное предложение является бессоюзным. АГ-80 предлагает рассматривать его как сложносочиненное с причинно-следственным значением. То есть фактически предлагается выделять «причинно-следственные» отношения и в группе сложносочиненных, и в группе сложноподчиненных предложений.

Словари (во многом, вероятно, вслед за АГ-80) идут еще дальше. Лексическое значение слов (это наречия причины) позволяет отмечать у предложения причинно-следственное значение, поэтому словари начинают вносить изменения в характеристику указанных лексем. В словаре В.В.Бурцевой указано, что *потому* и *поэтому* «присоединяют придаточное предложение причины, вследствие этого, поэтому» (с. 501, 508). То есть предложения с этими лексемами оказываются сложноподчиненными. При этом, заметим, *потому* названо союзом (с. 501), а *поэтому* – союзным словом (с. 508).

Другие словари оказываются более последовательными. В новом толковом словаре, составленном в Институте русского языка им. В.В.Виноградова, оба слова охарактеризованы как «наречия и союзные слова». Однако из такой словарной характеристики следует, что ряд авторов АГ-80 изменили точку зрения не только на суть самих лексических единиц, но и на характер сложных предложений, вводимых и Союзное слово используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях... Союзное слово используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях… вводимые [части] оказываются при этом понимании придаточными причины или следствия. **Окончательный ответ на данный вопрос следует ожидать только в новой академической грамматике русского языка.**

Но до выхода в свет новой грамматики проблему грамматического статуса слов *потому* и *поэтому* следует считать неурегулированным. Научные дискуссии могут вестись, автор научной монографии имеет право придерживаться какой-либо своей точки зрения, но мы убеждены, что в учебных пособиях сегодня должна быть отражена традиционная позиция.

Она предельно четко сформулирована в РЯ МГУ: «Не относятся к СПП с придаточным следствия: <..> 3. Предложения, части которых соединены сочинительной или бессоюзной связью и во второй части которых представлены наречия *потому* и *поэтому:* *Была хорошая погода, и потому мы отправились на озеро* (ССП); *Пошел дождь, поэтому нам пришлось уйти* (БСП)»

Итак, мы показали несколько взглядов: традиционный, авторский (достаточно противоречивый) и академический, тоже не отличающийся последовательностью. Считаем, что определенная, увы, неразбериха, появляющаяся в разных пособиях (в том числе электронных), не должна повлиять на разбор темы «Союзные слова» при её изучении и повторении при подготовке к выпускным экзаменам. Поэтому следует обязательно просматривать используемое на уроках пособие, ведь в части из них содержатся ошибки. О том, как их обнаружить, чтобы не принять ошибку за «новый взгляд на науку», мы и попытались рассказать.

*Академическая грамматика русского языка (АГ-80)

http://fs.nashaucheba.ru/docs/270/index-1415178.html

Comment: + см. обсуждение здесь: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4594&p=243514&hilit=%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9F#p243514

Comment: + по поводу Вашего, Серж, предложения.=== Николенкова:

"Исходя из традиционного понимания морфологического статуса «поэтому» данное предложение является бессоюзным."

Answer (score 2):

Такие предложения, по-моему, относятся к бессоюзным. *Поэтому* - наречие, союзом не является.

Если выбирать из Ваших версий, я бы больше склонилась к сложноподчинённому с придаточным, приближенным к присоединительному: "Она вышла замуж и изменила фамилию, что и привело к тому, что мы не могли ее найти". А вот Грамматику-80 я часто не понимаю. *Потому* - причинное наречие, как оно может передать сочинительные отношения? Если только присоединительные.

Comment: Вот что пишет Грамма.ру. 
  Предложения типа **"Она вышла замуж и изменила фамилию, поэтому мы не могли ее найти"**и в самом деле трактуются в "Русской грамматике", изданной в 1982 году,
как сложносочиненные, хотя и имеющие при этом причинно-следственное
значение. Дело в том, что слово "поэтому" не является союзом -
следовательно, не может вводить придаточное предложение. "Поэтому" -
наречие, выступающее как обстоятельство причины во второй части сложного
предложения, - становится аналогом сочинительного союза, выражающего
определенный вид несобственно соединительных отношений.

Comment:  Это мнение
Грамматики-80. Есть и другая точка зрения, которая нам кажется более
логичной: такие (то есть формируемые не союзами, а полнозначными словами
и сочетаниями, выступающими в роли связки) предложения можно
рассматривать как один из видов бессоюзных предложений.

Comment: Людмила, да, это бессоюзное предложение. По поводу ''поэтому'': тут много противоречий. Справка в одном из своих ответов, говорит, что "поэтому" -  союз. У Ожегова (в старом издании) - союзн. слово и местоим. В новом - наречие. В большом толковым словаре - союзн. слово и наречие.

Comment: Ответ Граммы.ру
Вопрос о том, как квалифицировать предложения, соединяемые словом "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и т.д., зависит от того, на каком основании проводить границу между союзными (сложносочиненными и сложноподчиненными) и бессоюзными сложными предложениями.
Если следовать определениям, которые обычно даются в научной и учебной литературе, то части союзного сложного предложения должны соединяться союзами и союзными словами.

Comment: Нетрудно заметить, что слова  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр. не подходят ни под союзы, ни под союзные слова, так как это вводные слова, частицы и наречия. Именно на этом основании сложные предложения, части которого соединены такими словами, традиционно относятся к числу бессоюзных. 
В таком подходе есть, конечно, определенная натяжка, так как очевидно и то, что перечисленные слова и им подобные выступают в качестве средств связи.

Comment: Поэтому некоторые лингвисты предлагают относить сложные предложения, части которых соединены словами  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр., к числу союзных предложений, относя эти слова к аналогам союзов. Именно так поступает "Русская грамматика". Вопрос о том, к каким именно союзным сложным предложениям относить предложения с этими словами, остается дискуссионным. "Русская грамматика" их относит к сложносочиненным предложениям, так как эти слова могут выступать в качестве конкретизаторов сочинительных союзов: "а/и поэтому", "и/а/но все-таки" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Считается, что в том случае, когда слова  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки"  выступают самостоятельно, они как бы включают в свой состав отсутствующий сочинительный союз. Другие лингвисты исходят из семантики слов  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" : в одних случаях их значение ближе к подчинительным союзам, в других случаях - к сочинительным союзам. На этом основании аналоги союзов относят к подчинительным или сочинительным.