# Тип сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Я недавно пришла работать в школу, а вот институт, наоборот, закончила давно. Не на все вопросы могу найти ответ в книгах, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

**Погода была плохая, поэтому мы остались дома.**

Это сложноподчиненное или бессоюзное предложение?
Я бы назвала его СПП, но в списках союзов и союзных слов  нет слова "поэтому".
Но ведь можно заменить на "так что", значит, это все-таки союз и сложноподчиненное предложение со значением следствия?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже обсуждался на этом форуме. [Предложение ССП или ССП](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Comment: Лера, раз вы работаете в школе, то может Вы знаете, какова точка зрения учебников, по которым Вы преподаете?

Comment: Слова "поэтому" нет в списке союзов и союзных слов, значит, авторы считают его наречием. То есть предложение бессоюзное. Но я не согласна.

Comment: В словарях есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я бы назвала его СПП, но в списках союзов и союзных слов **нет слова**
>   **"поэтому"**.

**Есть.** Есть у Бурцевой, у Кузнецова, у Светлышевой...

Тем не менее на вопрос --

> Предложение "Погода была плохая, поэтому мы остались дома" -
>   сложноподчиненное или бессоюзное?

-- отвечу так:

[***"Исходя из ТРАДИЦИОННОГО понимания морфологического статуса «поэтому» данное предложение является бессоюзным."***](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Но это только пока оно является таким. Что будет завтра?.. Думаю, интересующимся данным вопросом будет интересно мнение автора множества научных работ, вузовских и школьных учебников **Веры Васильевны Бабайцевой:**

> Сложные предложения с ***поэтому*** занимают зону синкретизма между
>   СБП и союзными предложениями. **Такие предложения нельзя
>   квалифицировать однозначно**, так как они обнаруживают признаки всех
>   трёх типов сложных предложений: СБП, ССП и СПП.
>
> При необходимости однозначной квалификации сложных предложений с
>   ***поэтому*** (например, в учебных целях) их можно сближать с **СПП** с придаточными следственно-присоединительными. Слово ***поэтому*** по
>   своей семантике близко к союзному слову ***отчего*** и в некоторых
>   случаях может быть заменено им.
>
> **(Бабайцева В.В. "Явления переходности в грамматике русского языка",**
>   **М., 2000)**

Comment: Я имела в виду авторов школьных учебников.

Comment: slava, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Погода была плохая, поэтому мы остались дома.

Это БСП неоднородного состава, вторая часть является следствием первой. Наречие «поэтому» является не союзом, а дополнительным структурным элементом, именно оно и выражает грамматическое значение предложения. Соответственно, здесь не требуется такой сильный знак, как тире.

Сравнить: Дорога  была плохая — людей в кузове швыряло из стороны в сторону.
Дорога  была плохая, поэтому людей в кузове швыряло из стороны в сторону.

БСП — это сложное предложение, части которого соединяются без помощи союзов или союзных слов, основное средство связи - интонация. Грамматическое значение сложного предложения - это смысловые отношения между предикативными частями.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос я недавно задал ***Грамме.ру.*** Вот их ответ.

> Вопрос о том, как квалифицировать предложения, соединяемые словом "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и т.д., зависит от того, на каком основании проводить границу между союзными (сложносочиненными и сложноподчиненными) и бессоюзными сложными предложениями.
>   Если следовать определениям, которые обычно даются в научной и учебной литературе, то части союзного сложного предложения должны соединяться союзами и союзными словами. Нетрудно заметить, что слова  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр. не подходят ни под союзы, ни под союзные слова, так как это вводные слова, частицы и наречия. Именно на этом основании сложные предложения, части которого соединены такими словами, традиционно относятся к числу бессоюзных. 
>   В таком подходе есть, конечно, определенная натяжка, так как очевидно и то, что перечисленные слова и им подобные выступают в качестве средств связи. Поэтому некоторые лингвисты предлагают относить сложные предложения, части которых соединены словами  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр., к числу союзных предложений, относя эти слова к аналогам союзов. Именно так поступает "Русская грамматика".
>   Вопрос о том, к каким именно союзным сложным предложениям относить предложения с этими словами, остается дискуссионным. "Русская грамматика" их относит к сложносочиненным предложениям, так как эти слова могут выступать в качестве конкретизаторов сочинительных союзов: "а/и поэтому", "и/а/но все-таки" и т.д. Считается, что в том случае, когда слова  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки"  выступают самостоятельно, они как бы включают в свой состав отсутствующий сочинительный союз. Другие лингвисты исходят из семантики слов  "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" : в одних случаях их значение ближе к подчинительным союзам, в других случаях - к сочинительным союзам. На этом основании аналоги союзов относят к подчинительным или сочинительным.

Comment: Наречие "поэтому" выражает семантику отношений, но не служит средством связи. Сравнить: Погода была плохая, мы поэтому остались дома. Это БСП?  Или союз находится в середине предложения?

Comment: Вера, а что наречие не может выступать в роли союзных слов?  В приведенном вами предложении, конечно, ''***поэтому***'' не выступает в качестве связующего звена, но вот в вопросе автора местоименное наречие выступает в качестве союзного слова,что также фиксируется в его словарных описаниях.

Comment: Серж, таких наречий, частиц, вводных слов, помогающих определиться  с семантикой, очень много, они могут находиться в любом месте. Если их все считать союзами, то получится большая путаница. У союза две функции - грамматика (связь) и семантика, а у остальных слов только семантика, надо отличать грамматическую функцию слова от семантической. Вот еще пример: Погода была плохая, и поэтому мы остались дома. Это уже ССП, союз И выражает грамматику, а наречие - семантику отношений.

Comment: Вера, что тогда по-вашему союзные слова? Какова их роль?

Comment: И еще: какова семантика ''поэтому" по-вашему?

Comment: Существует три взгляда на этот вопрос. И Грамма.ру подробно описала их.

Comment: Но вопрос в другом: к какому  типу такие предложения относят в школе. Вы знаете?

Comment: 1) Наречие "поэтому" имеет значение следствия в любом случае. 2) Союзные слова, как и союзы,   служат для связи предложений, но, в отличие от союзов,  дополнительно являются членами предложения. 3) Наличие трех взглядов на одну проблему  усложняет нашу жизнь, а жизнь школьных учителей тем более. В то же время ничто не мешает нам лично выбрать одну из точек зрения и обосновать ее. 4) Я не знаю, как эта проблема решается в школе, но подозреваю, что она решается по-разному.

Comment: Да, Вера, Вы правы: ничто не мешает нам лично выбрать одну из точек зрения и обосновать ее.

Comment: В СПП с придаточным следствия называется ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ союз ТАК ЧТО: погода была плохая, так что мы остались дома. (Русский язык, 9 класс, 21 изд., 1999 год). Можно заметить, что ПОЭТОМУ и ТАК ЧТО имеют разные значения: чистое следствие у ТАК ЧТО и причинно-следственное или пояснительно-следственное значение  у ПОЭТОМУ. Слова вида ПОЭТОМУ называют еще анафорическими элементами, они отсылают нас назад, к первому предложению, таким образом обозначается взаимная связь двух предложений.

Comment: Хотя формулировка МГУ тоже не вполне понятна. Предложения с ''потому'' они относят к ССП, в то время как предложения с "поэтому" к БСП. В словаре Кузнецова "потому'' - союз.