# Предложение с "поэтому" — подчинительная связь?

Tags: синтаксис

В ответах тестов ОГЭ написано, что в этом предложении есть и сочинительная, и подчинительная связь. Но разве ПОЭТОМУ является подчинительной связью?

> Ему очень не хотелось тащить эти мимозы, но мама просила, и
>   расстраивать ее тоже не хотелось, поэтому он взял три веточки мимозы и
>   пошел в школу.

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался на этом сайте. [Тип сложного предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419417/%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: [Предложение сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то перепутали. Там нужно найти среди предложений 18-20 предложение, где есть и сочинительная, и подчинительная связь.

(18)Ему очень не хотелось тащить эти мимозы, но мама просила, и расстраивать ее тоже не хотелось, поэтому он взял три веточки мимозы и пошел в школу.
(19)По дороге ему казалось, что все на него оглядываются, но у самой школы ему повезло. (20)Он встретил Лену Попову, подбежал к ней, протянул мимозу и сказал:
- Это тебе.

Понятно, что это предл.19.

Answer (score 0):

Включать подобные предложения в тесты в корне неправильно, т.к. вопрос, к какому типу относятся  предложения со словом "поэтому", является спорным.

Вот что пишет Грамма.ру.

Вопрос о том, как квалифицировать предложения, соединяемые словом "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и т.д., зависит от того, на каком основании проводить границу между союзными (сложносочиненными и сложноподчиненными) и бессоюзными сложными предложениями. Если следовать определениям, которые обычно даются в научной и учебной литературе, то части союзного сложного предложения должны соединяться союзами и союзными словами. Нетрудно заметить, что слова "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр. не подходят ни под союзы, ни под союзные слова, так как это вводные слова, частицы и наречия. Именно на этом основании сложные предложения, части которого соединены такими словами, традиционно относятся к числу бессоюзных. В таком подходе есть, конечно, определенная натяжка, так как очевидно и то, что перечисленные слова и им подобные выступают в качестве средств связи. Поэтому некоторые лингвисты предлагают относить сложные предложения, части которых соединены словами "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" и пр., к числу союзных предложений, относя эти слова к аналогам союзов. Именно так поступает "Русская грамматика". Вопрос о том, к каким именно союзным сложным предложениям относить предложения с этими словами, остается дискуссионным. "Русская грамматика" их относит к сложносочиненным предложениям, так как эти слова могут выступать в качестве конкретизаторов сочинительных союзов: "а/и поэтому", "и/а/но все-таки" и т.д. Считается, что в том случае, когда слова "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" выступают самостоятельно, они как бы включают в свой состав отсутствующий сочинительный союз. Другие лингвисты исходят из семантики слов "поэтому", "значит", "следовательно", "все-таки" : в одних случаях их значение ближе к подчинительным союзам, в других случаях - к сочинительным союзам. На этом основании аналоги союзов относят к подчинительным или сочинительным.