# Поэтому - какая часть речи?

Tags: синтаксис

Какой частью речи является слово "ПОЭТОМУ" и какое будет предложение с ним - сложноподчиненное или бессоюзное?

В варианте ЕГЭ составители утверждают, что это СПП, а я помню, что нам профессор говорил в институте, что это наречие, поэтому предложение бессоюзное получается.

Император планировал возвести под крышу стены здания до конца года, поэтому работы велись круглосуточно, число рабочих достигало единовременно 6 тысяч.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438378/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c

Comment: Я просмотрела предыдущие ответы, и вот что меня в них не устраивает. Одни лингвисты и другие лингвисты должны обозначить систему классификации сложных предложений,  которой они пользуются, а уже на ее основании делать вывод. Сейчас в вузах применяется СОВРЕМЕННАЯ и вполне определенная система, и, как кажется, она всех устраивает. Четкое описание, четкие определения. Если пользоваться именно этой моделью, но все определяется однозначно, что и важно для школьного и вузовского образования.

Answer (score 2):

*Император планировал возвести под крышу стены здания до конца года, **поэтому** работы велись круглосуточно, число рабочих достигало единовременно 6 тысяч.*

Это **бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП)**, а наречие ПОЭТОМУ является **союзным аналогом**.

Союзных аналогов у нас  много – это **наречия, частицы, вводные слова**, их еще называют структурными элементами или конкретизаторами значения.

При сочинительной или бессоюзной связи, если отношения между предложениями **неоднородные**, союзные аналоги служат для выражения этого значения (причины, уступки  и др.).

**Чем они отличаются от союзов?** Они не входят в общую модель для трех видов сложных предложений. Формальными средствами связи являются сочинительные союзы (ССП), подчинительные союзы (СПП) и интонация (БСП).

Сочинительные союзы делятся на соединительные, разделительные, противительные и др.
Подчинительная связь бывает союзной и местоименной, там своя классификация.

Куда же "податься" нашему наречию ПОЭТОМУ?

Хотел было пойти в подчинительные союзы **со значением следствия**, там же всего один союз ТАК ЧТО, но отказали. Почему? Дело в том, что ПОЭТОМУ соединяется с сочинительным союзом И, образуя союзное единство, а вот союз ТАК ЧТО этого не делает, он правильный и самостоятельный. В сочинительные союзы, понятное дело, тоже не возьмут.

Поэтому служит наше наречие союзным аналогом в БСП и в ССП.

Answer (score 2):

> В варианте ЕГЭ составители утверждают, что это СПП, а я помню, что нам
> профессор говорил в институте, что это наречие, поэтому предложение
> бессоюзное получается.

Несколько десятилетий назад "поэтому" всеми словарями считалось наречием, и исходя из такого понимания его морфологического статуса предложения с "поэтому" считались бессоюзными. Но время шло…

Пять лет назад в ответе на аналогичный вопрос (см. **[Тип сложного предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419417/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)**) я приводил ссылку на мнение автора множества научных работ, вузовских и школьных учебников Веры Васильевны Бабайцевой:

> Сложные предложения с ***поэтому*** занимают зону синкретизма между
> СБП и союзными предложениями. Такие предложения нельзя квалифицировать
> однозначно, так как они обнаруживают признаки всех трёх типов сложных
> предложений: СБП, ССП и СПП.
>
> При необходимости однозначной квалификации сложных предложений с
> ***поэтому*** (например, в учебных целях) их можно сближать с СПП с придаточными следственно-присоединительными. Слово ***поэтому*** по
> своей семантике близко к союзному слову ***отчего*** и в некоторых
> случаях может быть заменено им.
>
> (Бабайцева В.В. *"Явления переходности в грамматике русского языка"*,
> М., 2000)

Ну а как трактуется морфологический статус "поэтому" в сложных предложениях в словарях, вышедших в последние годы?

У Кузнецова в *БТС* — союзное слово (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83&all=x);

у Бурцевой в *"Словаре наречий и служебных слов русского языка"* (М., 2010) — союзное слово;

в *"Орфографическом словаре русского языка"* Букчиной и др. — союз (https://orthographic.academic.ru/60538/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)… (Кстати, этот словарь находится в официально утвержденном «списке грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации». — см. http://slovari.gramota.ru/biblio/research/slovari-norm/text/)

К союзным словам относит "поэтому" и *"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка"* под ред. В.В. Морковкина (М., 2016):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> В варианте ЕГЭ составители утверждают, что это СПП...

Ну, если это действительно так, то значит, что одной неурегулированной проблемой в синтаксисе русского языка становится меньше…

Answer (score 0):

**О синкретизме в мозгах** (к отвечающим на вопрос это никак не относится!)

«Сложные предложения с ***поэтому*** занимают зону синкретизма между СБП и союзными предложениями…»

Из словарей:

**СИНКРЕТИЗМ** – нерасчлененность, характеризующая неразвитое состояние какого-либо явления.Краткий словарь **философских терминов.**

**Словарь по культурологии.** Синкретизм. (греч. synkretismos – соединение). Качество, свойственное первобытной культуре, характеризующееся нерасчлененностью и неразвитостью чего-либо, в частности деятельности и сознания.

**СИНКРЕТИЗМ** (от греч. synkretismos — соединение)— 1) совпадение в процессе развития языка функционально различных грамматических категорий и форм в одной форме. В рус. яз. наблюдается, напр., падежный С. (одно окончание имеет значение разных падежей) или С. разных грамматич. категорий (одно окончание имеет значение определ. рода, числа и падежа).

Мне не нравится само слово «синкретизм», а  также то, что оно обозначает: **первобытность и неразвитость  явления**. Еще бы, первобытное сознание еще нечетко ориентировалось в мире.

Но время шло…

Человек становился более развитым и сделал много открытий в разных областях жизни. И самое главное, он научился **сравнивать предметы, сопоставлять, систематизировать**. Классификация растительного и животного мира (заслуга Линнея), классификация химических элементов (великий Менделеев). Все открытия начинались с этого, организованному ученому сознанию мы обязаны тем уровнем жизни, который имеем сейчас.

**А что же лингвистика?** В языке синкретизм – совпадение грамматических форм, и это можно объяснить. Возможности языкового общения не так велики, к примеру, мы можем произнести ограниченное количество звуков.  А интонационные возможности речи? Увы, они тоже ограничены звуковыми характеристиками. Поэтому одни и те же  интонационные модели приходится использовать в разных ситуациях.

**А вот мышление  видимых границ не имеет,** там нет показаний для синкретизма. Человек может создать для одного явления **несколько описательных моделей и выбрать наилучшую.** Поэтому синкретизм в описательной грамматике приветствовать нельзя, там это именно неразвитость и несовершенство.

**Но время-то идет, нам не надо оставаться в прошлом веке!**

Вот синтаксис, она мне кажется самым динамичным направлением в современном языкознании.

«Поэтому» – это наречие? А кто говорит иначе, в классификации частей речи это именно наречие. Принадлежность к определенной категории в этой области определяется достаточно четко. Переход частей речи возможен, но это также фиксируется правилами, **просто так в другую часть речи не запишешься**, даже, например, в союзы.

**Союзное слово?** Но это не союз, а местоимение, которое принимает участие в образовании местоименной связи вида «то…что, тот…который». Союзный аналог? И для него есть четкое современное определение.

**Синкретизм в грамматических описаниях**, размытость, нечеткость, смешение разных систем классификации – вот что можно назвать неурегулированной проблемой, "но, кажется, таких проблем становится всё меньше".

Так что давайте отдадим должное тем людям, которые сделали многое для развития языка, **но отложим в сторону их старые учебники**. Классификационная модель современного синтаксиса ушла от синкретизма, там всё четко и однозначно. Возможно, эта модель будет развиваться и дальше, но пока желательно ориентироваться именно на нее, хотя это, конечно, ваш выбор.

**Толковые словари, ЕГЭ  – у них своя функция.** Грамматику надо изучать по грамматическим монографиям, а не по словарям. Даже в этом синкретизм оказывает свое негативное влияние.

Помните, как у Булгакова: " Обедать надо в столовой, спать – в спальне..." Поэтому – долой синкретизм!