# "Поэтому" может быть союзным словом?

Tags: наречия

Во втором задании ЕГЭ нужно вставить **союзное слово** на месте пропуска. Вот текст:

«Существуют настолько массивные космические объекты, что они не могут посылать вообще никаких сигналов. Огромная сила тяготения этих небесных тел удерживает даже световые лучи, (?) такие тела называют чёрными дырами. Они удерживают свет, как наша Земля удерживает твёрдые предметы, а так как мы можем видеть только те тела, которые излучают или отражают свет, чёрные дыры навсегда останутся для нас невидимыми».

Учитель говорит, что ответ "поэтому", но разве это не наречие?

Comment: Недавно на сайте был похожий вопрос. Думаю, что эта информация может быть полезной. (Поэтому - какая часть речи?) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461294/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8

Answer (score 3):

Между местоименным наречием и союзным словом "поэтому" грань весьма зыбкая: и то и другое указывают на "вот почему".

Рассмотрите примеры из словаря:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я согласна с учителем:

*Огромная сила тяготения этих небесных тел удерживает даже световые лучи, поэтому* (союзное слово) *такие тела называют чёрными дырами.*

Answer (score 1):

*Огромная сила тяготения этих небесных тел удерживает даже световые лучи, **поэтому** такие тела называют чёрными дырами.*

1. Сюда походит только слово "поэтому". Можно ли его считать  союзным словом (ведь в толковом словаре так написано)? Увы, есть много причин в этом усомниться,  об этом и пойдет речь.

С другой стороны, **вам придется писать** то, что скажет учитель, и **то, что от вас ждут составители ЕГЭ.** Вся остальная информация для тех, кто еще не отвык думать, анализировать, сравнивать.

2. Рассмотрим предложение: *«Гусь взял в клюв другую веревочку и потянул, **отчего** тотчас же раздался оглушительный выстрел» (А.П. Чехов).*

И давайте сравним два таких предложения:

(1)  *Гусь потянул веревочку, **отчего** раздался выстрел.*

(2)   *Гусь потянул веревочку, **поэтому**  раздался выстрел.*

2. К первому предложению нет вопросов, классификация его давно известна: сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным **присоединительным**.

Слово **«отчего»**  также имеет постоянную «прописку». Часть речи: местоименное наречие (грамматическая классификация), а по семантической классификации – вопросительное или относительное слово.  **Такие относительные слова  в синтаксисе называют союзными словами.**

3. А вот второе предложение **как классифицировать**? Предложите это сделать себе, своему учителю, составителям вопросов по ЕГЭ, а также авторам толкового словаря.
4. А пока давайте сделаем это сами.

Если «поэтому» считать союзным словом, то это сложноподчиненное предложение, но вот какое? Придаточное **следствия или тоже присоединительное?**

Обратим внимание **на корневую основу «что»** во всех союзах и союзных словах. В  наречии  «поэтому»  нет такой основы, там **основа «это».** Называют «это»  анафорическим местоимением (отсылающим нас назад,  к уже сказанному).  «Это» в разных формах очень часто используется в речи,  вот и в наречии «поэтому»  (поэтому, по этой причине) мы его видим.

Обычно эти падежные формы на роль союзного слова  в бессоюзных предложениях **не претендуют,** например: Мы заблудились, этого я и боялся (БСП). Сравнить: Мы заблудились,  чего я и боялся (СПП). Это пример из современного синтаксиса.

А вот местоименному наречию «поэтому»  очень  хочется стать союзным словом:  *Гусь потянул веревочку, **поэтому (по этой причине)**  раздался выстрел.*

Но это **БСП с присоединительным значением** (дополнительное указание **на причину**).

Сравнить:  *Он запер сейф,  **для этого** он и приезжал*  (дополнительное указание на **цель**).

Так неужели **все эти формы** (этого, за этим, для этого, по этой причине, поэтому) мы  будем считать союзными словами?

Может быть, и будем, если грамматику изучать **по толковым словарям**. А пока **«анафорические»  слова**  не проходят проверку ни по каким показателям. Пока еще **союзные слова – это относительные слова**, указанные в классификации местоимений. Они соотносятся с вопросительными словами (что, как, зачем, отчего).

Итак, "поэтому" – это **местоименное наречие**, которое в БСП может быть **союзным аналогом.** Связь там бессоюзная, а наречие дополнительно указывает **на значение причины.** У него не грамматическая, а только семантическая **функция.** Такую функцию могут выполнять различные части речи: частицы, наречия, вводные слова, но в **грамматический класс союзных слов** они не входят.

Для справок:

1. **Примечание.** Кстати, в толковом словаре написано, что «отчего»  в придаточных присоединительных  – это **союз,** в то время как всем известно, что это союзное слово.  Еще одно открытие! Так что можно сказать при проведении грамматического анализа: **осторожно, толковый словарь!**

**ОТЧЕГО.** I. местоим. нареч. Почему? по какой причине? О. не пришёл? Не знаю, о. так случилось. **II. союз.** Вследствие чего, по причине чего. Старик улыбнулся, **отчего** лицо его покрылось морщинами.

2. Розенталь: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-195.htm#i12973

**Присоединительные придаточные** содержат дополнительное сообщение по поводу высказанного в главной части предложения.

Дополнительное сообщение может заключать в себе пояснение, оценку данного в главной части сообщения, вывод из него или добавочные замечания, связанные с содержанием этого сообщения… придаточная часть несамостоятельна, так как имеет **формальный показатель подчинения – союзное слово.** Это союзное слово как бы вмещает в себя содержание предшествующей главной части (целиком или частично).

Comment: Я бы отнёс вторую часть предложения к присоединительным конструкциям (ПК). _Присоединительное предложение_ как частный случай ПК (Розенталь упоминает такую возможность, приводя примеры с союзами "да и" и "и" в присоединительном значении) в нашем примере не является придаточным. Если заменить "поэтому" на "и" смысл и грамматика предложения не изменятся, а поскольку "и" после замещения оказывается присоединительным _союзом_, то "поэтому" выполняет в предложении функцию **союза**, а не союзного слова (поскольку здесь не СПП, к которому отсылает определение союзного слова).

Comment: А то, что выглядит как союз и действует как союз, союзом в рамках такой ситуации и является, независимо от местоименно-наречной или иной этимологии слова. Терминология же "союзный аналог (аналог союза)" мне кажется не слишком полезной: выражение "может быть союзным аналогом" = "может выполнять функцию союза" (выступать как часть речи под названием "союз").

Comment: Пожалуйста, определите вид сложного предложения,включающего две предикативные основы. У вас три варианта: СПП, ССП, БСП, другого не дано. Наречие явно имеет причинное значение (поэтому - по этой причине), это семантика СПП или БСП. Если наречие - это союз, то связь союзная, остается только СПП. Определите вид придаточного. Присоединительное? Следствия?  Это наречие не подойдет, я уже приводила примеры. Там нужны ТАК ЧТО (следствие) или ОТЧЕГО (присоединительное), то есть основа с корнем  "что". Не может это наречие  быть союзным словом, не вписывается в этот грамматический класс.

Comment: В крайнем случае можно сказать, что оно выполняет функцию союзного слова. Но это по семантике, а не по грамматике, то есть это БСП. Можно, конечно, всё упрощать, считать союзными словами любые местоимения, но кому нужен такой грамматический анализ. Настоящее союзное слово - это местоименное наречие по грамматике и относительное местоимение по семантике, это общепринятая и давно известная классификация. Об этом был вопрос. А у вас получается. или местоименное наречие, или союзное слово.

Comment: Это "причинное значение" наследует при подстановке союз "и" - его ведь не пытаются в таких ситуациях назвать "наречным аналогом".