# Что означает выражение "употреблено в значении союза"?

Tags: грамматика, союзы

**Можно ли вообще так говорить?** И если это корректное выражение, то в каких случаях оно используется?

Рассмотрим, к примеру, два предложения:

1) *Я занят, **так что** приехать не могу.* Здесь союз **так что**  со значением следствия в СПП.

2) *Я занят, **поэтому** приехать не могу.*  Здесь наречие с тем же значением.

Но в словаре говорится, что ***поэтому*** ―  союзное слово. Тогда это предложение надо считать сложноподчиненным?

(Заметим, кстати, что в СПП такой структуры  **союзные слова вообще не используются,** они характерны для местоименной связи или для изъяснительных предложений).

Если же это БСП, то там **нет ни союзов, ни союзных слов,** но есть конкретизаторы значения (наречия, вводные слова, частицы), которые уточняют отношения между частями сложного предложения.

**Так как правильно:** союзное слово, наречие в значении союза или просто наречие, уточняющее смысловое отношение?

***Для справок***

Союз ― это служебная часть речи, служащая для **формального** соединения различных синтаксических единиц. Союзы делятся на два разряда: сочинительные и подчинительные.

(Кроме союзов, в СПП используются союзные слова, которые являются членами предложения).

Comment: *>> Я занят, поэтому приехать не могу. Это наречие, знаменательное слово (член предложения)*. Какой именно?

Comment: Я полагаю, что обстоятельство.

Comment: А где написано "в значении союза"? У Кузнецова – союзное слово.

Comment: Действительно, союзное слово. Поэтому я изменила текст вопроса.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже обсуждался. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ссылку, я этого обсуждения не видела, но сейчас прочитала. Кроме того,  эта тема постоянно присутствует при грамматическом анализе, не замечать ее и обходить стороной бывает сложно, поэтому приходится  принять какую-то точку зрения. Я попробую сама ответить на  вопрос.

**ОТВЕТ**

Я думаю, что выражения "употреблено в значении союза" или "является аналогом союза" **нежелательно использовать, так как смысл их неясен.**

В действительности речь о словах, которые в качестве **структурных элементов** используются для **дополнительной связи** между частями предложения или входят в союзные соединения (и поэтому, а поэтому, между тем как). Можно сказать коротко: используются **в качестве структурных союзных элементов**.

Такие элементы **не являются основными средствами связи**, как союзы и  союзные слова (или интонация в БСП), но **дополняют их**.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ** (ответ на вопросы: **В каких сложных предложениях (СПП, ССП, БСП) используется наречие "поэтому"? Можно ли это наречие считать союзом или союзным словом?)**

1. Союз ― **формальное средство** связи (это служебное слово, не является членом предложения), следовательно наречие  ***поэтому*** нельзя назвать союзом (знаменательное слово может быть только союзным словом).
2. Наречие имеет значение вывода, следствия, но союзные слова **в СПП с придаточным следствия не применяются.**

Пояснение: Союзные слова используются с СПП с местоименной связью и в некоторых изъяснительных предложениях, а в придаточных цели, следствия, причины и др. используются только союзная связь.

3. Союзное слово **не может использоваться в БСП** (там нет ни союзов, ни союзных слов)
4. В ССП используется **только союзная связь**
5. **Вывод: наречие "поэтому" нельзя считать союзом или союзным словом.**

В качестве **союзного слова** оно не может использоваться ни в одном из видов сложного предложения.

Чтобы стать **союзом**, оно должно утратить значение знаменательного слова и стать формальным средством связи.

**Решение задачи**

*Я занят, **поэтому** приехать не могу.* Это БСП, наречие использовано в качестве структурного элемента ― конкретизатора значения.

Я занят, **и поэтому** приехать не могу. Это ССП, наречие входит в составной сочинительный союз И ПОЭТОМУ (уточняет значение союза И).

**Редакция словарной статьи:**

**ПОЭТОМУ.** I. местоим. нареч. По этой причине, вот почему. Опоздал из-за пурги? - Да, п. II. Структурный элемент со значением следствия в БСП. Стало темно, п. зажгли лампу. Входит в состав сочинительных союзов И ПОЭТОМУ, А ПОЭТОМУ, ПОЭТОМУ И. Уже поздно, а п. поторопись. Неудачник, п. и озлоблен.