# Мы тоже учли полученный опыт(,) и поэтому

Tags: синтаксис, ссп

Запутался с синтаксисом, как результат - не могу понять, нужна ли тут запятая - и почему. Вот фраза, как она в черновике написана.

*Мы тоже учли полученный опыт(,) и поэтому с нового сезона помощь  будет оказываться в первую очередь тем, кто знает, как с ней поступать.*

Фраза, понятно, шероховата и будет изменена во второй своей части, но интересует не стилистика, а именно запятая перед "и поэтому" - вкупе с грамматическим разбором, желательно.

//==========

Судя по всему моими сомнениями прониклись. )))
Тогда обратный пример.

*В последние несколько дней он был очень занят, и поэтому встретиться с корреспондентом "Известий" не сумел.*
("Известия", цитирую по НАЦКОРПУСУ)

Здесь уж никак не ССП, а запятая стоит. Ошибка, получается, если следовать логике и разбору от @Alex_ander. Но таких примеров в Нацкорпусе изрядно.

Comment: А что, обычное ССП уже отменили?!

Comment: @Niemand читайте метки, прежде чем умничать,

Comment: @Niemand А обратный пример и не должен "говорить" о чем-то в отношении прямого. Читайте основы логики, здесь это - "не формат". Надеюсь, что владеющий вопросом поймет, зачем тут этот пример.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь ССП, не подпадающее под исключения без запятой (общий второстепенный член, общее придаточное и пр.):  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm

Минимальным изменением, убирающим запятую, было бы приведение частей предложения к общему подлежащему:

> Мы тоже учли полученный опыт и поэтому с нового сезона помощь будем
>   оказывать в первую очередь тем, кто знает, как с ней поступать.

Ввиду неоднородных сказуемых это промежуточный тип предложения между ССП и простым осложненным:  http://www.filologdirect.narod.ru/sra/sra_2006_09.html

Comment: Вы "поэтому" каким союзом считаете? Сочинительным или подчинительным?

Comment: *Минимальным изменением, убирающим запятую,* - судя по Нацкорпусу (пример - в тексте вопроса) пунктуационная практика свидетельствует об обратном. В ьаких конструкциях запятая чаще присутствует., даже когда иных мотивов для неё нет.

Comment: @behemothus *Вы "поэтому" каким союзом считаете?* — посмотрите об этом [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/48023/183462). Ваша статистика ошибок по Нацкорпусу немного удивляет, поскольку в гугло-книгах я не смог найти ни одной такой ошибки.

Comment: "Поэтому" (в отличие от имеющегося союза "и") здесь функционирует как обстоятельство причины: оно легко заменяется и более распространёнными оборотами (в результате, на основании этого опыта и т. п.), но может быть опущено без изменения пунктуации.

Comment: @grizzly спасибо, конечно, за ссылку, но мнение Николенковой мне хорошо известно, я собственно, и не собираюсь с ней спрорить. Интересует подход именно Alex_ander'а,

Comment: *Поэтому"...  здесь функционирует как обстоятельство причины* - то есть вы не считаете "поэтому" союзом (как и союзным словом) вообще?! Это да, многое бы объясняло, включая вашу безапелляционности. Но дело-то в том, что тут есть большой подводный камень. "Поэтому"  и "потому" не имеют даже отдаленных синонимов , которые бы были безусловными местоимениями/наречиями без функций союза. Уберите в тексте "И"  - и вы скорее всего признаете предложение сложноподчиненным. Еще явственнее это выступает при перечислениях казалось бы однородных членов: "голодыій, (a) поэтому злой".

Comment: Впрочем, ладно. Не вы первый.   Хотя та же Николенкова, хотя и стоит насмерть за "школьный" подход, признает наличие определенной логики и в АГ